# Add a param to a function that contains a default param

Tags: javascript

I have a code as following :

```
{
    headerName: "A",
    valueGetter: 'data.a',
    field: 'a',
    cellRenderer:ACellRenderer,
    width: 100,
    filter: 'number'
}
```

And this :

```
function ACellRenderer(params){
    if(params.data && params.data.a){
        // Do something
    }
}
```

I don't understand where that params parameter came from, as I only call the `ACellRenderer` without any params.

I also want to call `ACellRenderer` with a param I pass to it, apparently doing this : `cellRenderer:ACellRenderer(myParam)` won't work.

Comment: Could you give more background on your code? What happens with that JS object?

Comment: The line `cellRenderer:ACellRenderer,` **does not** call the `ACellRender` function. It just stores it into the `cellRenderer` property of an object. Calling a JavaScript function requires the parentheses after the function name, even if it doesn't have any arguments. e.g `ACellRenderer()`.

Comment: You're not even calling the function...

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a hard time understanding your question from the way it's worded, but perhaps you're looking to do this?

```
{
    headerName: "A",
    valueGetter: 'data.a',
    field: 'a',
    cellRenderer:function(){ACellRenderer(<put your parameter here>);},
    width: 100,
    filter: 'number'
}
```

Also, for future reference, the common term is `argument`, not `param`. Not that it matters that much, but it'll help you be understood better by other Javascript programmers.

Comment: The cellRenderer accepts a function as following : `function ACellRenderer(params){...}` I don't know where params came from but I use it inside my function definition, now I want to pass another argument to this function so the function I store in `cellRenderer` will be as following : `function ACellRenderer(params, type){...}` but I don't know how to pass my second argument.

Comment: @IchigoKurosaki Exactly like you said, just use a comma.

Answer (score 0):

This :

```
var Obj = {
    headerName: "A",
    valueGetter: 'data.a',
    field: 'a',
    cellRenderer:ACellRenderer,
    width: 100,
    filter: 'number'
}
```

Is just a definition of an object.

This line : `cellRenderer:ACellRenderer` Stores the function in that particular variable Basic JS like this :

```
var func = function(){}
```

Now calling it will be like :

`Obj['cellRenderer']();`

OR

`Obj.cellRenderer();`

The function expects an object as a parameter, i don't see how that is confusing.

Comment: `Obj[cellRenderer]();` will not call the function. Use either `Obj.cellRenderer();` or `Obj["cellRenderer"]();` instead (preferably the first one). The way it is in this answer will try to access the property with the name stored in the global `callRenderer` variable, which will almost certainly be `undefined` or some irrelevant value.

Comment: i missed `'` sorry, calling this way `Obj['cellRenderer']();` has it's own advantages, as if you have multiple function inside a function and you're looping thought it.

Comment: I personally wouldn't use the bracket notation unless the property being accessed can change but I suppose it could be useful as well.

Comment: It is useful otherwise it wouldn't be there, anyway i will adjust the answer.

Comment: Thanks ZohirSalak